# plotly how to convert a named color to rgb in python?

Tags: plotly-python

I am looking for a function like

```
convert_function("red")  -> result: ‘rgb(255, 0, 0)’ or (255,0,0)
```

The function should work on all plotly named colors (including css colors like springgreen)

Comment: in my program, I get named colors as inputs and I need to fade them before using them.

Comment: Note you might be able to set the opacity on markers and lines among other things to fade them (sort of) without having to convert to rgb. Otherwise you can look at the `plotly.colors` module but I don't think there is a function for this as plotly.py uses plotly.js so the (css) named colors don't need to be converted.

Comment: There is a `name_to_rgb()` function in the [webcolors](https://pypi.org/project/webcolors/) module, which is precisely designed for working with HTML/CSS color definitions.